# Identification of Rare Newton Statue

Tags: newton

[image]

I'm not sure where else to post this. No matter how inventive my Google searches, I am unable to locate an active webpage containing this rare statue of Isaac Newton that I stored on my computer a number of years ago. Can anybody identify information about this statue?

Comment: I found a page with Google Lens but it's in Chinese.

Comment: wow - nothing from google image search!      Also - @Spencer  can't you use GoogleTranslate on that page you found?

Comment: Any chance there's some EXIF data in your original image?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Not that I know of.

Comment: @Spencer Can you link the page? I had tried a reverse image Google search a while ago, but even that failed.

Comment: FWIW: https://www.828la.com/p/53586.html

Comment: Thanks this is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is a lead:  I found an [article](http://en.broad.com/m/NewsDetail-48-3.aspx) which includes the following text [emphasis mine] .

> The campus of Broad Group in Changsha was designed to reflect Zhang
> Yue’s eclectic influences and his passion for the environment. It
> encompasses a sprawling organic garden that provides up to half of the
> food consumed by his workers, and the grounds are dotted with dozens
> of statues of inspirational figures, from Confucius and the poet Li
> Bai to Coco Chanel and Jack Welch. There are likenesses of
> environmentalist Rachel Carson, ***Sir Isaac Newton with an apple about
> to fall on his head***, and Winston Churchill flashing a V for Victory
> sign. One company building is modeled after the palace at Versailles,
> another after an Egyptian pyramid.

Comment: Interesting.  I used Google Maps to see if street-view or satellite-view would show anything: [Changsha - Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Changsha,+Hunan,+China/@28.1714027,112.953951,2882m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x342735f39e1c64c5:0xb1e5bb9ca1f1a680!8m2!3d28.228209!4d112.938814).
Strangely, switching between "map" and "satellite" causes the street overlays to shift by about 600 metres (for Americans, that's 3 furlongs).  Apparently this is something China does with GPS coordinates to discourage spying on them.

Comment: Interesting, how did you find this?

Comment: @user7348 I set the Google search string to something like  "China statue Isaac Newton apple falling on head"  and lucked out   :-)

Comment: @Carl Without Interesting, I tried the same thing and came up blank. It must be sensitive to an exact word search.

Comment: @user7348  or  Google Search treats me as a "SuperUser"  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Carl Witthoft's lead, I found another image at this [link](http://www.zhongguoyx.com/jingcaihuigu/2956.html).  To locate the image, you can search the page for the text "第五章：科技筑梦" to avoid lots of scrolling. The image, shown below, provides the full background text:

没有大胆的猜测

就没有伟大的发现

(paraphrasing google translate, this comes out to: "Without bold guesses, there is no great discovery")

[image]